# I am making a game, and I want a number to be added to a label when the user taps a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am making a game, and I want a number to be added to a label when the user taps a button. Like it adds 5 points when the button.

Comment: nothing yet . i cant figure out how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IBAction button to label output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755784/ibactionbutton-to-label-output) or [Incrementing a number and showing steps on a label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237621/obj-c-incrementing-a-number-and-showing-steps-on-a-cocoa-label)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;` and implement this method:

```
   -(IBAction)buttonPressed {
      scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[scoreLabel.text intValue]+5];
    }
```

Make sure you set up the connections in the IB (scoreLabel points to the label and the button triggers the action.

Comment: the app crashes. i add the outlet for the label, and the action for the button, and connected everything, but it gives me an alert: "Passing argument 1 of 'setText:' makes pointer from integer without a cast."

Comment: @ryan: Sorry, the text of a label must be a string. I revised my code.

Comment: thank you so much! this helped me out alot! im 14, and this is going towards my game which is going to be in the app store. have a great day @pengone!

Answer (score 0):

In Cocos2d you can create labels that can have a numerical value attributed to them.
The pseudocode for this question would be as such:

```
int points = 5;

UIButton *pushButton;
UILabel *Label;

-(void)OnButtonPress{
points =+ 5 //add 5 points
}

label.text = [NSString stringWithInt:points];
```

For a tutorial on Cocos2d labels, please see:
http://www.usightread.com/2009/06/labels-menus-and-options-in-cocos2d-iphone/

Comment: im having some trouble putting it in the .m - wouldnt i put: - (IBAction)pushButton:(id) sender { first ?