# Increment the value by 1 each time a UIButton is touched

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, for-loop

I using core data and an sqlite db to store some data. There's an attribute called entity.amount that I'm looking to increment the value of by 1 each time a UIButton is touched.

I'm thinking that I might need a for-loop, but can't figure out the syntax with the core data entity involved.

thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [(IBAction)button to label output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755784/ibactionbutton-to-label-output) or [Incrementing a number and showing steps on a label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237621/obj-c-incrementing-a-number-and-showing-steps-on-a-cocoa-label)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// if you have your button in a view controller

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)buttonPress:(id)sender {
    //get your core data entity and call it something like model

    model.amount++;
    [managedObjectContext save:error];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop? No, you need to have an action method on that button and inside that action method, you simply increment the value. That's all. BTW, if you are using Xcode 4, you can literally create an action method by dragging and dropping the button. See figure 4.10 and 11 in the link below.

[Xcode 4 Transition Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html)

Comment: thanks for your response. I have the UIButton and IBAction in place already. It's the code to increment that I need help with. Any tips on how to do that? thanks

Comment: Travis has the right idea (though I would do it differently): a model object in the controller with a property that gets incremented is all there is to this. Then save that one object.